# How to substitute this method with a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I am making a simple voting system (My first project) and I used a method that is very primitive by using the same index in 2 different lists to link 2 objects. Ex. I have a list called (names) where I stored the names of the candidates in the election then I made another list called (votes) to store the votes for each candidate and I matched the indexes so that the votes for the candidate with index 1 in the list (names) is stored in the same index (1) in the other list (votes). I thought about using dictionaries but a 2D seemed better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2D list is just a list-of-lists. You could create one for your voting system and add votes to it as shown below. The 2D `voting_system` list is being created by something known as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I put the data involved in variables to make the process more "data-driven" and easier to change.

```
from pprint import pprint

Candidate_A, Candidate_B, Candidate_C = 'George', 'Kamala', 'Michele'
candidates = Candidate_A, Candidate_B, Candidate_C

print('Using a 2D list:')
voting_system = [[name, 0] for name in candidates]  # Create 2D list.
pprint(voting_system)  # Show initial values.

voting_system[candidates.index(Candidate_B)][1] += 1  # Add a vote for Candidate_B.
pprint(voting_system)  # Show updated values.
```

Output:

````
Using a 2D list:
[['George', 0], ['Kamala', 0], ['Michele', 0]]
[['George', 0], ['Kamala', 1], ['Michele', 0]]```
````

#### Update - Using a dictionary

You never said why you thought using a 2D list seemed better than a dictionary — and I think you should reconsider because there are some advantages. The most important being that you don't need to explicitly find the index of the candidate in order to update the number of votes they have, which on average would involve checking half of all of them in the list. Looking that up in dictionary is the same, very fast, speed regardless of the number of candidate involved. I also think the syntax is a little simpler and easy to read.

Here's how to do things with a dictionary:

```
from pprint import pprint

Candidate_A, Candidate_B, Candidate_C = 'George', 'Kamala', 'Michele'
candidates = Candidate_A, Candidate_B, Candidate_C

print('Using a dictionary:')
voting_system = dict.fromkeys(candidates, 0)
pprint(voting_system)  # Show initial values.

voting_system[Candidate_B] += 1  # Add a vote for Candidate_B.
pprint(voting_system)  # Show initial values.
```

Output:

```
Using a dictionary:
{'George': 0, 'Kamala': 0, 'Michele': 0}
{'George': 0, 'Kamala': 1, 'Michele': 0}
```